# Append lists from different csv files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, opencsv

I am trying to append several lists each from a different csv files in Python. Here is the code I am using:

```
from_ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
to_ls = [2,3,4,5,6]
mylists = []
for i in range(len(from_ls)):
    from_ = from_ls[i]
    to_ = to_ls[i]
    print(str(from_)+'-'+str(to_))
    f = 'data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv'
    if os.path.exists(f):
        with open('data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            mylists.extend(reader)
        print('file '+f+' append successfully')
    else:
        print('file '+f+' not found')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
1-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "_io.TextIOWrapper") to str
```

I know that `f = 'data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv'` creates an `_io.TextIOWrapper` but I don't know how to turn it into a string so that I can read the file.

I have tried to read the csv files individually as below and it works fine:

```
i=0
from_ = from_ls[i]
to_ = to_ls[i]
with open('data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    mylists = list(reader)
```

Comment: What is `text`?

Comment: I have corrected: it is actually mylists

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your error, but I couldn't. However I've found some mistakes.

```
import os
import csv

from_ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
to_ls = [2,3,4,5,6]
mylists = []
for i in range(len(from_ls)):
    from_ = from_ls[i]
    to_ = to_ls[i]
    print(str(from_)+'-'+str(to_))
    fname = 'data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv'
    if os.path.exists(fname):
        with open(fname) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            mylists.extend(reader)
        print('file '+fname+' append successfully')
    else:
        print('file '+fname+' not found')
```

I do not have csv files here. Try to see if it corrects your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

```
    print('file '+f+' append successfully')
else:
    print('file '+f+' not found')
```

`f` is the variable you assigned `open('data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv')` to.

Although you have `f = 'data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv'`, you have overwritten its value later in the code. Simply change the name of one of your variables.

Corrected version:

```
from_ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
to_ls = [2,3,4,5,6]
mylists = []
for i in range(len(from_ls)):
    from_ = from_ls[i]
    to_ = to_ls[i]
    print(str(from_)+'-'+str(to_))
    fn = 'data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv' # Note the change of variable name
    if os.path.exists(fn): # And here
        with open('data'+str(from_)+'to'+str(to_)+'.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            mylists.extend(reader)
        print('file '+fn+' append successfully') # Here
    else:
        print('file '+fn+' not found') # Here also
```